# Matching a Regex against a multiline string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I am trying to match a Regex against a multi-line string, but the match fails after the first line.

These expressions work as expected:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile("a")
>>> a = "a"
>>> r.match(a)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>
>>> a = "a\n"
>>> r.match(a)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>
>>>
```

Whilst this expression does not work:

```
>>> a = "\na"
>>> r.match(a)
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) was designed to match from the first character (the start) of the string.  In the first two examples, the match works fine because `a` is the first character.  In the last example however, the match fails because `\n` is the first character.

You need to use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) in this case to have Python search for the `a`:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile("a")
>>> a = "\na"
>>> r.search(a)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 2), match='a'>
>>>
```

Also, just a note: if you are working with multi-line strings, then you will need to set the dot-all flag to have `.` match newlines.  This can be done with [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL).

Answer (score 2):

**Why doesnt `match` work?**

`match` searches the pattern at the start of the string.

**How to correct?**

use `search` instead

```
>>> import re
>>> pat=re.compile('a')
>>> pat.search('\na')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7faef636d440>
>>>
```